# Selfish mining attack: Probability of block being mined - CS251 exam question

Tags: attack, selfish-mining

I am currently studying for the CS251 Cryptocurrencies and Blockchain Technologies exam. In a past exam, there is this question without an answer and I would really appreciate your help so that I can better understand it:

*Recall that a selfish miner temporarily refrains from publishing mined blocks in an
effort to get several blocks ahead of other miners, thereby causing other miners to
waste effort mining orphan blocks. When a selfish miner is only one block S ahead of
the public chain, if another miner mines and publishes a block O at the same height as
S, the selfish miner immediately publishes S. Let γ be the probability that, when this
happens, an honest miner will try to mine the next block on S instead of on O.*

*A) How can an attacker ensure that γ ≈ 1 (in other words, S almost always overrides O) on today’s Bitcoin network?*

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: A guess: what if the selfish miner deliberately omits from S a number of high-fee transactions that are in O?  Then other miners have an incentive to mine on S, because then they can claim the fees of those transactions, whereas with O they could not.

Comment: @NateEldredge That's a good one! I would not have thought of that.

Comment: @NateEldredge thanks! So you mean the selfish miner omits the high transaction fee transactions so that miners have the chance to get a block with them for the next block?

Comment: @Python-Data-Science-Learner: Right.  But I don't know if that's what your exam has in mind.  I also don't know whether your exam would consider a miner "honest" who would  mine on S instead of O to get more fees, despite having seen O first.